# Setting eosio.code permission for contract account in eosjs

Tags: eosjs, eosio-code, permissions

I am trying to set the `eosio.code`  permission for my contract on account `kbo2byvpkbiy` (private blockchain). The reason I want to do this is calling eosio.token/transfer from within this contract.

All I have figured out so far is the following code:

```
await contractApi.transact({
    actions: [{
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'updateauth',
        authorization: [{
            actor: "kbo2byvpkbiy", 
            permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
            account: "kbo2byvpkbiy",  
            permission: "active",
            parent: 'active',
            auth: {
                "threshold": 1,
                "keys": [{
                    "key": "EOS6gmCFLGxcAkKRskJKBPwXdFwZSJ7TPz2RRpXU1Lyn5e3zXrEFm",
                    "weight": 1
                }],
                "accounts": [{
                    "permission": {
                        "actor": "kbo2byvpkbiy",
                        "permission": "eosio.code"
                    },
                    "weight": 1
                }],
                "waits": [
                    {
                        "wait_sec": 0,
                        "weight": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
});
```

When I use this I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot set an authority as its own parent at new RpcError
```

What am I doing wrong? The correct cleos command (after importing the private key into my wallet is:

```
cleos set account permission kbo2byvpkbiy active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS6gmCFLGxcAkKRskJKBPwXdFwZSJ7TPz2RRpXU1Lyn5e3zXrEFm","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor": "kbo2byvpkbiy","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}'
```

But how do I do this correctly in eosjs?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Option**
Get your account data from the chain. The result should contain `required_auth.accounts` property. Push to that array an object like

```
{ permission: { actor: accountName, permission: 'eosio.code' }, weight }
```

Once pushed update your account on chain like this

```
eosjs.transaction(tr => {
        tr.updateauth({
            account: 'Your account name',
            permission: 'active',
            parent: 'owner',
            auth: 'The updated **required_auth** object'
        }, { authorization: [Your account name@active] });

  }, { broadcast: true, sign: true, keyProvider: 'Private key of your account' });
```

**2. Option**
In your provided object

```
 data: {
            account: "kbo2byvpkbiy",  
            permission: "active",
            parent: 'active',
            auth: {
                "threshold": 1,
                "keys": [{
                    "key": "EOS6gmCFLGxcAkKRskJKBPwXdFwZSJ7TPz2RRpXU1Lyn5e3zXrEFm",
                    "weight": 1
                }],
                "accounts": [{
                    "permission": {
                        "actor": "kbo2byvpkbiy",
                        "permission": "eosio.code"
                    },
                    "weight": 1
                }],
                "waits": [
                    {
                        "wait_sec": 0,
                        "weight": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Set parent prop to 'owner' instead of 'active'

**3. Option**

Check out eoslime as it is based on eosjs. There is `account.addPermission('eosio.code')` method. You could check out their code to figure out how they do it